# NVD3.js | php | unix time stamp not working

Tags: javascript, php, nvd3.js

For some reason the timestamps i am using are not translating to the graph correctly.  the graph says they are 01/16/1970 [ time stamp: 1389429242].  I am using strtotime (php function) to generate the time stamps.  How do i generate the correct time stamp for this to work, using php?

Code:

```
<script>
    nv.addGraph(function() {
        var chart = nv.models.lineWithFocusChart();

        chart.xAxis
            .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d)) });
        chart.x2Axis
            .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d)) });

        chart.yAxis
            .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));
        chart.y2Axis
            .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));

        d3.select('#chart svg')
                .datum(
                    [
                        {
                            key : 'Current' ,
                            color : '#2ca02c',
                            values : [
                                { x: 1389429242 , y:15 },
                                ...
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            key : 'Backlog' ,
                            color : '#ff7f0e',
                            values : [
                                { x: 1389429242 , y:50 },
                                ...
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                )
                .call(chart);

        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

        return chart;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently, JS time stamps are in milliseconds.  So i had to multiply my php time stamp my 1000 and it works.

SOLVED